# Responsive Variable for Browser Window Width [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, variables, resize, window-resize, window-width

I'm trying to have a variable that constantly updates whenever the browser window is resized in terms of width (in pixels). I do not want the page to have to refresh for the variable to change, but rather have the variable change as the window is resized.

I do not want the variable to be written in the html document either, as I use this variable mathematically further down the script before it has any effect.

Here is the closest I think I got to the answer.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var windowwidth = window.innerWidth;
};

window.onresize = function() {
  var windowwidth = window.innerWidth;
};

console.log(windowwidth);
```

**ANSWER BELOW**

```
window.onload = function() {
  currentWidth(document.body.clientWidth);
};

window.onresize = function() {
  currentWidth(document.body.clientWidth);
};

function currentWidth(w) {

// Math using w goes here

}
```

Comment: Why are you storing window width in variable?, you can directly use `window.innerWidth` wherever is require. just suggestions. If there is any reason to do this please explain. Thanks

Comment: Because it will not update for when the Windows is resized

Comment: `window.innerWidth` this is always current width of your browser

Comment: If I refresh the page yes, but without refreshing the page it won't constantly update as I resize the browser window

Answer (score 0):

Use the following JS Code at your end and resize the window. you can see the value of variable change on resizing the window.

```js
var a = Math.random();
console.log (a);
window.onresize = function()
{
    a = Math.random();
    console.log (a);
}
```

Comment: hi,

sorry if I didnt explain it right. I didnt want a random number to equal the variable. I was after the width of the browser window in pixels, and have it update as the window is resized.

for instance:

When the window is 1920 px wide, a === 1920.

When the window is 500 px wide, a === 500.

Answer (score 0):

call the function inside the callback

```js
window.onload = function() {
  currentWidth(window.innerWidth);
};

window.onresize = function() {
  currentWidth(window.innerWidth);
};

function currentWidth(w) {
  console.log(w)
  console.log(w > 500)
}
```

Comment: Hi,
Thank heaps I can see it updating in the console! however I'm not too sure what to use for the maths later. When I use w later in the script (example ((w + 2) / 3) it says w is undefined. and when I use currentWidth in the same way it still says undefined. Sorry if this is a stupid question I just don't know which variable to plug into everything else.

Comment: undefined in IE9? try `currentWidth(window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth);`

Comment: I was using Google Chrome

Comment: please update your question above and add complete code

Comment: I will just absent from my computer right now. Will do when I can